# PHP 7 querying JSON data type mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5

I have data in MySQL db, table 'user', column 'attributes' with json type as follow :

```
{"hp": {"base": 10}}
```

I tried to query database json data using laravel with following :

```
$users = Users::where('attributes->hp->base', 10)->get();
```

but it returns empty result. So tried to get the query using following :

```
$users = Users::where('attributes->hp->base', 10)->toSql();
```

and it shows me the query as :

```
select * from users where attributes->"$.hp.base" = ?
```

now when I use that command in MySQL command line with following it works

```
select * from users where attributes->"$.hp.base" = 10
```

So, I tried using native php :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = 'select * from users where attributes->"$.hp.base" = 10';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

it still shows 0 results. what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Where you select database name using myslqi??

Comment: Darn, I forgot to put in the database name on native PHP. Now it shows the result for the native one. Need to figure out why laravel one isn't working. I tried Users::all() it works

Answer (score 1):

Thx to Saty comment about selecting database. so the answer for native PHP is :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

Now for laravel version, it needs to have DB::raw() according to https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13232

So laravel eloquent version will be :

```
$users = Users::where('attributes->hp->base', DB::raw(10))->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi Please change your query as given below

```
$sql = 'select * from users where attributes->"'.$.hp.base.'" = 10';
```

Comment: This doesn't even parse as PHP code; it fails at `$.`.